# Bitcoin money transfer

Tags: blockchain.info

I transferred money from circle to Bitcoin, the transaction showed it was successful however it did not go into my Bitcoin but went to blockchain. I saw the amount on blockchain as unspent but then after few days it was shown as spent. However it did not even reach me so can it show that and also why has it reached there and is there any way of getting it back. I look forward to hearing from you soon.

Comment: Hey Ali, welcome to Bitcoin.SE. Could you please clarify the following: Where were you trying to transfer money to? Was it circle to Bitcoin Core? Where did you see the amount as unspent, was it in Blockchain.info's block explorer, which shows you all transaction information, or in your online wallet account there? If you tried sending bitcoins to your Bitcoin Core, and saw the transaction on Blockchain.info's explorer, have you checked whether it got to your Bitcoin Core?

Answer (score 1):

Weird. If you don't mind, could you add a transaction I'd and your bitcoin wallet address?

I'm guessing you withdrew into your bitcoin wallet from circle, but it didn't appear in your bitcoin wallet. You could however see it on the blockchain?

I have a couple of ideas:

1. Malware

   - You may have malware installed on your computer that swaps out your bitcoin address that you have copied down to the hacker's bitcoin address. Please verify that the recieving address in the blockchain is the same one as the one in your wallet.
2. Wallet not synced

   - If you're using a wallet like bitcoin core/qt, you will have to wait for your wallet to sync. It will show at the bottom of the client.